# Foreign characters in apps on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, operating-system, osx-yosemite

Has anyone else but me gotten foreign characters in specific apps after installing Yosemite Beta?! I've got Dropbox and Spotify in Chinese now...

Comment: please add some details

Comment: Solved it - turns out several applications installed interpreted the system to be Japanese rather than English. Had to figure out how to change the language settings for each application, as changing the language systemwide had no effect.

Comment: Please post the solution as answer, may prove helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "System Preferences > Language & Region". In the section "Preferred languages" reorder them by dragging the ones you prefer to the top of the list. Restart your system.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, go to "System preferences > Languages" and exclude foreign languages.